# How to convert base64 to xml in dataweave?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I'm trying to convert the following payload to xml, but facing errors.

```json
{
  "RelayState": "/",
  "SAMLRequest": "PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48c2FtbDJwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdCB4bWxuczpzYW1sMnA9InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDpwcm90b2NvbCIgQXNzZXJ0aW9uQ29uc3VtZXJTZXJ2aWNlVVJMPSJodHRwczovL2JheWVybi1pbm5vdmF0aXYtLWtvbW1kaWdpZC5zYW5kYm94Lm15LnNhbGVzZm9yY2UuY29tP3NvPTAwRDNNMDAwMDAwOHBXRCZhbXA7c2M9MExFM00wMDAwMDAwMFNVIiBEZXN0aW5hdGlvbj0iaHR0cDovL3Nzby10ZXN0LXBvYy51cy1lMi5jbG91ZGh1Yi5pby9zc28iIElEPSJfMkNBQUFBWXVwTnhlck1EQXdNREF3TURBd01EQXdNREF3QUFBQTlyTWN6U3Azb0x4aldLeWVfcVVYV0RUZ0VqbjBaT3BEYUEwNkx6X184UGF4S2M1dFd0bWdkdm4zaHVia0M3cHZieXlUTjRYN0RBYUZXUExsTU1BRHJrNE90MzdPemJOQ3R6dnZqa1k1R2pDdVhtOFJfcXRNWUZMdXhmZGRJLV9OT2Myd2szMUdnamtTckxDRVdONnhaRDNqb3lkeHNBSG5kWFF6UnZWUE96OUQ0TGE3cVdSdjI2azRFR3RIZkV5UVpvT0RhNG9GeVBHN1VXemprMW9vdEdnQjVxSmpvRWpGclNJLWVhMnZDVmh2SDMtTk1GYm1KYUotbVdyaGxtREE5dyIgSXNzdWVJbnN0YW50PSIyMDIzLTEwLTEwVDA5OjU3OjI0LjQxMloiIFByb3RvY29sQmluZGluZz0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOmJpbmRpbmdzOkhUVFAtUE9TVCIgVmVyc2lvbj0iMi4wIj48c2FtbDI6SXNzdWVyIHhtbG5zOnNhbWwyPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6YXNzZXJ0aW9uIj5odHRwczovL2JheWVybi1pbm5vdmF0aXYtLWtvbW1kaWdpZC5zYW5kYm94Lm15LnNhbGVzZm9yY2UuY29tPC9zYW1sMjpJc3N1ZXI+PGRzOlNpZ25hdHVyZSB4bWxuczpkcz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC8wOS94bWxkc2lnIyI+PGRzOlNpZ25lZEluZm8+PGRzOkNhbm9uaWNhbGl6YXRpb25NZXRob2QgQWxnb3JpdGhtPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzEwL3htbC1leGMtYzE0biMiLz48ZHM6U2lnbmF0dXJlTWV0aG9kIEFsZ29yaXRobT0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMS8wNC94bWxkc2lnLW1vcmUjcnNhLXNoYTI1NiIvPjxkczpSZWZlcmVuY2UgVVJJPSIjXzJDQUFBQVl1cE54ZXJNREF3TURBd01EQXdNREF3TURBd0FBQUE5ck1jelNwM29MeGpXS3llX3FVWFdEVGdFam4wWk9wRGFBMDZMel9fOFBheEtjNXRXdG1nZHZuM2h1YmtDN3B2Ynl5VE40WDdEQWFGV1BMbE1NQURyazRPdDM3T3piTkN0enZ2amtZNUdqQ3VYbThSX3F0TVlGTHV4ZmRkSS1fTk9jMndrMzFHZ2prU3JMQ0VXTjZ4WkQzam95ZHhzQUhuZFhRelJ2VlBPejlENExhN3FXUnYyNms0RUd0SGZFeVFab09EYTRvRnlQRzdVV3pqazFvb3RHZ0I1cUpqb0VqRnJTSS1lYTJ2Q1ZodkgzLU5NRmJtSmFKLW1XcmhsbURBOXciPjxkczpUcmFuc2Zvcm1zPjxkczpUcmFuc2Zvcm0gQWxnb3JpdGhtPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwLzA5L3htbGRzaWcjZW52ZWxvcGVkLXNpZ25hdHVyZSIvPjxkczpUcmFuc2Zvcm0gQWxnb3JpdGhtPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzEwL3htbC1leGMtYzE0biMiLz48L2RzOlRyYW5zZm9ybXM+PGRzOkRpZ2VzdE1ldGhvZCBBbGdvcml0aG09Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDEvMDQveG1sZW5jI3NoYTI1NiIvPjxkczpEaWdlc3RWYWx1ZT5LQ1hoYjFUOUJLZUNPMWhxTXFOUjA0Sk1CenFDUUh2cWtCS0tuV3FrMDhNPTwvZHM6RGlnZXN0VmFsdWU+PC9kczpSZWZlcmVuY2U+PC9kczpTaWduZWRJbmZvPjxkczpTaWduYXR1cmVWYWx1ZT5IVkRlelB4VVd6Q043dnVBSEQrWi9hZnJ3V1BnZWVoYmZiZGhMYzlXNGFneWlNcjNxS2ltTWRTMGNqQ3hwNlg5SHU1ZGRxRmdtRDYzSCswR1Fidm5EUFNNK3FDY1dBdXMvdDVqSTVlN2Vod2xsUXhJeDZBdEZ3R1luN1hoLzZvL3p4RkR0V2x2YUx1RnBydk9jQkdEWmxNKzhkUlBFQ05JNTQ5K0RDZlZaUVB5cVRLSTc0SGgxejREcE9Fd2pKTTVrMHo4eTczY2I3MFFadE5QUnREYjE4aVgyL2J5clNTbTZ6VjFOSnY3aUUyYWVSeDJqT3l3NnB6Sk1CQ3dhYjFxamMzUzNTMEtjRlVvdTJDUSs4U0hScFpZdkNZd0JadGJjeHFSYjYvYjZrMzIvWVMzaVEwNzVnNmdaR29RRzJlNWkrVjhoTUNNVW9sNUhnUDJKNTlJOU9FaHVwMEVzY2lGNzg4SDZza3RwVjA1Z2s0QlNGTnduL2Z0K2xEc1VSWmVrR0cvZUNtZVpFbjVIK0N6WU5iaksrTklFck9XelFlRnNoWlJra1pLT0pzaFVUOXB2SU92Vm44NDRkaUJpNGRqZ1B5Q1ZrYkFCeGV2c1Q1L0xZZGZRSTNwU0t0WmxrZnk1ZGdqUWgvYWdnUVBYNTFtY044aXVCOHkyVTR5bU9LSStUQ3pLcndsYWR5RExHa0lJR3MyY3lEbC9KcEpXUERyaVZKOCtyQituU1kySzVGc3FDaUp1MjFNMUNsZEhuTTQxYnIwd2FPQnFYT05icTZHaFJPcW9wS3VzYmFzL2VxVVNTWGlJSUJSWmNabXZFd1o0MjZKVnErU2puN2p4ZWI4dTFQZ3Zzamx3R0RpaDZ5KzRpbGZzTlF1eUc3b3oyTXZFblV1aHdlYitoST08L2RzOlNpZ25hdHVyZVZhbHVlPjxkczpLZXlJbmZvPjxkczpYNTA5RGF0YT48ZHM6WDUwOUNlcnRpZmljYXRlPk1JSUdWVENDQkQyZ0F3SUJBZ0lPQVlnbEVxejRBQUFBQUEydWxhQXdEUVlKS29aSWh2Y05BUUVMQlFBd2RURU5NQXNHQTFVRUF3d0UKVGtWYVR6RVlNQllHQTFVRUN3d1BNREJFTTAwd01EQXdNREE0Y0ZkRU1SY3dGUVlEVlFRS0RBNVRZV3hsYzJadmNtTmxMbU52YlRFVwpNQlFHQTFVRUJ3d05VMkZ1SUVaeVlXNWphWE5qYnpFTE1Ba0dBMVVFQ0F3Q1EwRXhEREFLQmdOVkJBWVRBMVZUUVRBZUZ3MHlNekExCk1UWXhORFU1TWpCYUZ3MHlOVEExTVRZeE1qQXdNREJhTUhVeERUQUxCZ05WQkFNTUJFNUZXazh4R0RBV0JnTlZCQXNNRHpBd1JETk4KTURBd01EQXdPSEJYUkRFWE1CVUdBMVVFQ2d3T1UyRnNaWE5tYjNKalpTNWpiMjB4RmpBVUJnTlZCQWNNRFZOaGJpQkdjbUZ1WTJsegpZMjh4Q3pBSkJnTlZCQWdNQWtOQk1Rd3dDZ1lEVlFRR0V3TlZVMEV3Z2dJaU1BMEdDU3FHU0liM0RRRUJBUVVBQTRJQ0R3QXdnZ0lLCkFvSUNBUURUNXMxcEgzVnVSa2NmZUl2QldPMDZCcjBwUmY4VEtjUmlVTUVxc3JKeXZKRDBBYitSYkR2YjQ2VHBkOEhLajZwSllRT2MKeThHTDZVckpGVWFjb0MzNVo3V0lJQ1FtN0hXMkxtZXkrNGM5ck8zbzVMTFN2VGhybTAxN1VOS0ZzN041RW1jc0xsM1RKaXppU0JWUAovcXp2ODVIbTZhb01URmhEZmtLb2xDbHFXN1hzYkNKTmFzMU9UVmhFZFkxdTlNbjRvTzhSTk5Ka0czM2JMRTlQWklzWVJmQnUveGozClJCeUlKbjIrVXVoK1BmaTdlQ0l5bnVtWnhKYmhRdVlLYzFVUWQ5Z3UzWlZrU1dEMzYwUDhuc3k0WlkxbStEM3VzZ3VBK1JyZEFoQmYKd3BobzZIbjVFSXQzV1NwaG9ieDNDRUlRQS9pZGpSaWNwam1jc2hYdWlLN0VZcnBOaFU1ZE5LRGxDcWdtSm9wRzV5S2R6dHROdXJxSwp3cnVqaE8vbDNOYkVzYnpaVjdOZWcwdTlnd2ZVOFJEVUNYalYwRm82SVZKRmlHUjMxYloyL1ZDeWhvbFMrUFdyRlVRQ0Z6SFo5Q2YyClZ2YlZWcGs4ZkU4SU5hMFB3VWJ5UzRPaWR5ZDVwSktac0w2bk1vWVhGVC8rL1A1MTNFMitpa2czelRPbmFLS29VVlpBUUpVMEFRZ0MKaDd5dmhxNTdTSi84VnZuT3FrRmNrNC8rK0dFUHVnSWFjOWo3cWRFa2Uzazc2Wm1VUlQ4MkRaMmR3Zm52dGgvRS96dVoyaGw3V3NxUQo0enMrZm9SNGk3cmR2MFdDN1FRd3dqcWRXZTJzWE9KcVdOVEd0elZTVGYzbUQ2bXpjd2puVTdtSXQwbFJGRjFTR252U1BGR0VtVTRhCmVhTDRRd0lEQVFBQm80SGlNSUhmTUIwR0ExVWREZ1FXQkJSeSs5dllQQkxkbkhWeWYvMEkxdDFnejE3SmVEQVBCZ05WSFJNQkFmOEUKQlRBREFRSC9NSUdzQmdOVkhTTUVnYVF3Z2FHQUZITDcyOWc4RXQyY2RYSi8vUWpXM1dEUFhzbDRvWG1rZHpCMU1RMHdDd1lEVlFRRApEQVJPUlZwUE1SZ3dGZ1lEVlFRTERBOHdNRVF6VFRBd01EQXdNRGh3VjBReEZ6QVZCZ05WQkFvTURsTmhiR1Z6Wm05eVkyVXVZMjl0Ck1SWXdGQVlEVlFRSERBMVRZVzRnUm5KaGJtTnBjMk52TVFzd0NRWURWUVFJREFKRFFURU1NQW9HQTFVRUJoTURWVk5CZ2c0QmlDVVMKclBnQUFBQUFEYTZWb0RBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRc0ZBQU9DQWdFQUpTSUN6N3FrdHVMbU5kS3VnZUdMNzNDSEVMdTAzQkcwd0VMNgpNWHk0SXdrVTFRRjNzZWVhbVJYZUgwRDFRQWIyYitMSnlLbFFXaDQ2eGRrY25oeDVVWlVFa3lCZnhQVTNsRGhuV05SYlByZ01TQ0crClE1djF0VXdOSVZLRFB0SklubkRYaVc5d2xBRTJsblRnUVJXNUVqYklzZlVLWXJVY0FXSGQ1bWhSQ1VHbWh2QU9MQUdDZDc2S0pMZGUKQzhKMW5DcVdqMUxFSkdCeGdtdEdhZlRhS2N3eDhmZ2JtUjRycVRQNXIveXhqbVRHMXMwRVR4ZmFxaVgrcFdPdVVNWlVBT1ViMGpQRwp0aE95bndvR0t5NW9QR1UxZzEwbmNzRTBjNHNST2p5ZnhvL0dwU0w1Uk1ONlJKa1ltalFUNjZoaW56N1JPS2IrQi9oV2MyNURmRWJ2CjFlMUhYWjJaUjRCM0xrYTZzdnI2NUh1TURGbGJJajd3SEdVS2tJN2Q4OG81UW9BZ2JaVy9DaEVUL1lQb3h6eEZtcmR6Q1lXWnlCdUgKV2lBMytma0pwRUdBZWxaU1FXU2VyS0Zuc25hcTRXTGFYNEVkZmp2ZE9zU3RYN2Vxa3dFdS8yYkVOWW1qK1ZoYm5wRlRlQVljbHgybApxbEgzUlFJeCtsekowT3EzelcyaklwU3lFUDh5STF3UVFkMDV5bFpqaUg3NE1ROGVoRTdMcVRheWQ1RktIbHpHZ1NONkFYb3V4ZVBECk1JQmFYTDdicytKQ3NwN3BHdmFsbmZieVpmeTIyVnJ5OG5MUXZRQUJJVlZERWVGR0tYNCs5eGZtVExCbU5vQjhVVHFmMTkzNklaYXAKY3FSWFVqNEFIcm9Jd3lIc3JnZ3UzU2lFMWE2elIwRGRjNjE0OFRjPTwvZHM6WDUwOUNlcnRpZmljYXRlPjwvZHM6WDUwOURhdGE+PC9kczpLZXlJbmZvPjwvZHM6U2lnbmF0dXJlPjwvc2FtbDJwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdD4="
}
```

The "SAMLRequest" is base64 encoded and I need to convert it to xml.

I tried the fromBase64 function, i'm able to decode it, but conversion to xml isn't happening.

Comment: As far as I can tell the block of BASE64 encoded text contains valid XML. Can you edit your question to show us how you decode it and what you get when you do? You shouldn't need to convert anything.

Comment: @phuzi In DataWeave the `fromBase64()` function will return a binary. To parse it as XML the script needs an extra step. To say conversion to XML is misleading because it is not being converted, just parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [read](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-read) function here to read the payload as xml

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
import * from dw::core::Binaries
---
read(fromBase64(payload.SAMLRequest),"application/xml")
```

Comment: For this payload in the question it should be `payload.SAMLRequest`.